# Подсчет производной softmax функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, математика, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Пытаюсь понять более глубоко математику под капотом нейросетей. Застрял на подсчете  производной softmax функции. Нашел вот такое объяснение: https://medium.com/@aerinykim/how-to-implement-the-softmax-derivative-independently-from-any-loss-function-ae6d44363a9d.
Вот мой код на примере задачи удержания маятника:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env = env.unwrapped
env.seed(1)

max_episodes=1000
state_size = 4
action_size = env.action_space.n



def relu(x,deriv):
    if deriv:
        x[x<=0] = 0
        x[x>0] = 1
        return x
    else:
        return np.maximum(0,x)



def softmax(X, train):
    if train:
        max_prob = np.max(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
        X -= max_prob
        np.exp(X, X)
        sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X /= sum_prob[0]
    else:
        max_prob = np.max(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X -= max_prob[0]
        np.exp(X, X)
        sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X /= sum_prob[0]
    return X

def softmax_grad(s):
    # Reshape the 1-d softmax to 2-d so that np.dot will do the matrix multiplication
    s = s.reshape(-1,1)
    return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T) 

np.random.seed(1)

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((4,8)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((8,2)) - 1



def nn(x,y,train):
    global syn1,syn0
    l0 = x
    l1 = relu(np.dot(l0,syn0),deriv=False) 
    l2 = softmax(np.dot(l1,syn1),train=False)
    if train:
        y=np.array(y)
        l2_error = y - l2  
        l2_error = l2_error.reshape(20,1)
        l2_delta = l2_error*softmax_grad(l2)#<---странная матрица
        l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)#<--- Тут происходит ошибка
        l1_delta = l1_error * relu(l1,deriv=True)
        syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
        syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
    else:
        return l2

allRewards = []
total_rewards = 0
maximumRewardRecorded = 0
episode = 0
episode_states, episode_actions, episode_rewards = [],[],[]

for episode in range(max_episodes):
        episode_rewards_sum = 0
        state = env.reset()
        env.render()
        while True:
            action_probability_distribution = nn(x=state,y=_,train=False)
            action_probability_distribution=action_probability_distribution/sum(action_probability_distribution)
            action = np.random.choice(range(len(action_probability_distribution)), p=action_probability_distribution.ravel())
            new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            episode_states.append(state)
            action_ = np.zeros(action_size)
            action_[action] = 1
            episode_actions.append(action_)
            episode_rewards.append(reward)

            if done:
                episode_rewards_sum = np.sum(episode_rewards)
                allRewards.append(episode_rewards_sum)
                total_rewards = np.sum(allRewards)
                mean_reward = np.divide(total_rewards, episode+1)
                maximumRewardRecorded = np.amax(allRewards)

                print("==========================================")
                print("Episode: ", episode)
                print("Reward: ", episode_rewards_sum)
                print("Mean Reward", mean_reward)
                print("Max reward so far: ", maximumRewardRecorded)

                episode_states = np.array(episode_states)   
                nn(x=episode_states,y=episode_actions,train=True)               
                episode_states, episode_actions, episode_rewards = [],[],[]

                break

            state = new_state
```

Ловлю ошибку при обратном распространение. После использования функции softmax_grad выходит матрица с большой размерностью (20,20). Это происходит из-за матрицы Якоби. Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог этот вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36279904/softmax-derivative-in-numpy-approaches-0-implementation. Но еще предстоит до конца разобраться в математике. . .

Update:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
env = env.unwrapped
env.seed(1)

max_episodes=1000
state_size = 4
action_size = env.action_space.n



def relu(x,deriv):
    if deriv:
        x[x<=0] = 0
        x[x>0] = 1
        return x
    else:
        return np.maximum(0,x)



def softmax(X, train):
    if train:
        max_prob = np.max(X, axis=1).reshape((-1, 1))
        X -= max_prob
        np.exp(X, X)
        sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X /= sum_prob[0]
    else:
        max_prob = np.max(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X -= max_prob[0]
        np.exp(X, X)
        sum_prob = np.sum(X, axis=0).reshape((-1, 1))
        X /= sum_prob[0]
    return X

def softmax_grad(s):
    J = - signal[..., None] * signal[:, None, :] # off-diagonal Jacobian
    iy, ix = np.diag_indices_from(J[0])
    J[:, iy, ix] = signal * (1. - signal) # diagonal
    return J.sum(axis=1)

np.random.seed(1)

syn0 = 2*np.random.random((4,8)) - 1
syn1 = 2*np.random.random((8,2)) - 1



def nn(x,y,train):
    global syn1,syn0
    l0 = x
    l1 = relu(np.dot(l0,syn0),deriv=False) 
    l2 = softmax(np.dot(l1,syn1),train=False)
    if train:
        y=np.array(y)
        l2_error = y - l2 
        l2_delta = l2_error*softmax_grad(l2)#<---странная матрица
        l1_error = l2_delta.dot(syn1.T)#<--- Тут происходит ошибка
        l1_delta = l1_error * relu(l1,deriv=True)
        syn1 += l1.T.dot(l2_delta)
        syn0 += l0.T.dot(l1_delta)
    else:
        return l2

allRewards = []
total_rewards = 0
maximumRewardRecorded = 0
episode = 0
episode_states, episode_actions, episode_rewards = [],[],[]

for episode in range(max_episodes):
        episode_rewards_sum = 0
        state = env.reset()
        env.render()
        while True:
            action_probability_distribution = nn(x=state,y=_,train=False)
            action_probability_distribution=action_probability_distribution/sum(action_probability_distribution)
            action = np.random.choice(range(len(action_probability_distribution)), p=action_probability_distribution.ravel())
            new_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
            episode_states.append(state)
            action_ = np.zeros(action_size)
            action_[action] = 1
            episode_actions.append(action_)
            episode_rewards.append(reward)

            if done:
                episode_rewards_sum = np.sum(episode_rewards)
                allRewards.append(episode_rewards_sum)
                total_rewards = np.sum(allRewards)
                mean_reward = np.divide(total_rewards, episode+1)
                maximumRewardRecorded = np.amax(allRewards)

                print("==========================================")
                print("Episode: ", episode)
                print("Reward: ", episode_rewards_sum)
                print("Mean Reward", mean_reward)
                print("Max reward so far: ", maximumRewardRecorded)

                episode_states = np.array(episode_states)   
                nn(x=episode_states,y=episode_actions,train=True)               
                episode_states, episode_actions, episode_rewards = [],[],[]

                break

            state = new_state
```

Я заменил формулу функции softmax_grad
Ps: я просто скопипастил. Математику стоящую за функцией еще не до конца понял. Если кто сможет объяснить доступным языком, милости прошу)

Comment: Добавьте суть решения в сам ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите syn0=(4,8);syn1=(8,2).(1,4)x(4,8)=(1,8) функ_актив((1,8))=(1,8) Здесь нет произоводной софтмакс которая заменит матричный продукт,а есть np.dot,(1,8)x(8,2)=(1,2),функ_актив((1,2))=(1,2)-Здесь тоже такого нет.l2_error=(1,2)-(1,2)=(1,2).Зачем ее здесь решейпить в (20,1)?

Comment: Я пытаюсь вычислить производную софтмакс функции(softmax_grad) чтобы найти наклон для градиентного спуска. Решейп в (20, 1) я делаю для того чтобы перемножить ошибку l2_error с производной функции софтмакс во время обратного распространения(при train==True) так как размерность softmax_grad(l2) = (20,20). Заходя вперед, я также не понимаю как l2_delta должна перемножиться с l1_error в дальнейшем из-за такой большой размерности. Ps: я не знаю правильно ли делать тут решейп. Pps: я окончательно запутался. . .

Comment: Немудрено запутаться.Я тоже путался.Я делаю так:веса syn0=(4,8) syn1=(2,4) <syn0>:=(4,8)х<сигналы>:=(8,1)=(4,1),акт_фу((4,1))=(4,1),аналогично (2,4)х(4,1)=(2,1),функ_акт((2,1))=(2,1) loss_func=(2,1)-(2,1)=(2,1).Наклон на выходном слое (2,1)*произв((2,1))=(2,1).Перекидываем ошибку,транспортируя-(2,1).T *(2,4)=(1,2)х(2,4)=(1,4).Потом (1,4) ложится на элементы (2,4) "горизонтально"

Comment: Я понимаю, что наклон на выходном слое должен быть как вы описали(Наклон на выходном слое (2,1)*произв((2,1))=(2,1)). Однако моя функция softmax_grad выдает произв(20,20). С которой я не могу продолжать вычисления.

Comment: функция_актив не может выдавать квадратную(прямоугольную матрицу).Она выдает вектор сигналов или матрицу с количеством элементов 1,например (4,1).Может посмотрите мои опыты(не для рекламы,для пользы)http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/763551/

Comment: В своих опытах вы используете сигмоид функцию(nonlin). В моей задаче сигмоида может подойти, так как непосредственно эта среда имеет всего 2 действия. Однако я бы хотел использовать в дальнейшем кросс-энтропию как функцию потери и софтмакс функцию как функцию активации на выходном слое, так как многие другие среды имеют >2 действий(софтмакс функция выдает вероятность для каждого действия/класса).

Comment: Често говоря(я ведь сам учусь)я не вижу разницы между softmax и сигмоид,на 3 (например) выходных нейрона поставил сигмоид,и если он выдает >0.5 отнести его к 1-му из трех классов(остальные должны выдавать<0.5):)

Comment: К сожалению такой подход к моей задаче не подойдет :(